# Query Multiple Meta Values and display only when it has both meta values

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-value

I've been stuck on a problem for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to query posts and only display them if their 2 meta values checked contain the ones I have queried.

For example:

If a post had 123 and 321 then I want them to be displayed. But if it had 123 and 123 then it shouldn't be displayed and vice versa.

I have been looking at this code and I cant figure it out:

```
array(
       'key' => 'featured',
       'value' => 'yes',
       'compare' => 'NOT NULL',
    ),
 array(
       'key' => 'type',
       'value' => 'event',
       'compare' => 'NOT NULL',
    )
```

So just to clarify:

- if `featured` value is "yes" AND `type` value is "event" => it should
  be displayed

but

- if `featured` value is "yes" AND `type` value is "party" => it
  **shouldn't** be displayed.

Sorry if this doesnt make sense.

Thanks, Dazeh.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the `relation` parameter in [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). I'm assuming you are using the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class to make the call given your syntax in the example. You might want to ensure that no other plugins are forcing the relation parameter to be "OR" instead of the default "AND" by hooking into `pre_get_posts`.

```
$meta_query_AND = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
               'key' => 'featured',
               'value' => 'yes',
               'compare' => 'NOT NULL',
            ),
         array(
               'key' => 'type',
               'value' => 'event',
               'compare' => 'NOT NULL',
            )
     )
    );
$test_query = new WP_Query( $meta_query_AND );
```

The first step would be to evaluate the `meta_query` => `relation` value in your `wp_query` result.

Comment: relation is `AND` by [default](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L652). I think the problem is 'compare' argument...

Comment: good point - I was thinking that it was set by default but have seen in several plugins where the queries are dirtied by an unprotected relation set to OR and your answer for compare is a good point as well in order to be most explicit in the query.

Answer (score 1):

'compare' should be '=' because you are comparing exact values, also 'relation' have to 'AND'. Both should be default, but better to be sure

```
$meta_query = array (
  array(
    'key' => 'featured',
    'value' => 'yes',
    'compare' => '='
  ),
  array(
    'key' => 'type',
    'value' => 'event',
    'compare' => '='
  ),
  'relation' => 'AND'
);

$featured_events = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_query' => $meta_query ) );
```